# What are the minimum requirements of neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, docker, odroid, system-requirements

I'd like to use a neo4j database in a docker container with Odroid XU4. The database is not big, approximately 20.000 nodes will be in it. The Odroid has only 2G memory, and I'd like to have a samba server, some nodejs applications and at least one PgSQL database too, so the system is short on memory. I read in the [neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-requirements.html) that 2G memory is the minimum, but I read by [docker examples](http://lattice.cf/docs/docker-image-examples/) that it is used with 512M, so I am a little confused about this. What is the minimum memory I can use the neo4j docker image with?

I have similar troubles with the disk space. The system is on a 32GB SD card. I'd like to save database data there and backup on an external hard drive, so I could spend max 16GB for the neo4j. The data certainly does not require that kind of space, I am not sure why neo4j needs it (according to the manual again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can use http://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator/ to get rough estimate for memory and disk usage.

Second option is to do some math. You can use information on page 12 in http://graphaware.com/assets/bachman-msc-thesis.pdf

You should keep in mind it's good to have all data in the memory for the performance reasons.

From my point of view you shouldn't have problem with the memory, but you can't expect great performance.

It's better to try it by yourself before you ask here ;)